# Magento patch failing to install

Tags: php, magento, download, patch

When downloading and running the Magento PHP 5.4 support patch (Magento-CE-v1.7.0.0-1.7.0.2) from http://www.magentocommerce.com/download, running the script using `sh PATCH_SUPEE-2629_EE_1.12.0.0_v1.sh` we receive this error:

```
$ sh PATCH_SUPEE-2629_EE_1.12.0.0_v1.sh
: command not found_1.12.0.0_v1.sh: line 7:
'ATCH_SUPEE-2629_EE_1.12.0.0_v1.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `{
'ATCH_SUPEE-2629_EE_1.12.0.0_v1.sh: line 9: `_check_installed_tools() {
```

Strangely, line 7 of the script is blank (here's the head of the file):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Patch apllying tool template
# v0.1.2
# (c) Copyright 2013. Magento Inc.
#
# DO NOT CHANGE ANY LINE IN THIS FILE.

# 1. Check required system tools
_check_installed_tools() {
    local missed=""
```

We tried the download in Windows and Mac, in Firefox and Chrome to rule out any encoding problems caused by the download process. The patch seems to be very new - `Added Jan 17, 2014`

We're running Magento Community Edition 1.7.0.2

**Edit**

We've tried running the .sh file with `bash` as well but receive the same response.

Interestingly when the click "download", Magento shows the .sh source in the browser so we tried various combinations of view-source then save; copying the text from the browser window and saving it to a text file. None of these solved the problem although one changed the error message to:

```
$ sh PATCH_SUPEE-2629_EE_1.12.0.0_v1.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
/usr/bin/patch: **** malformed patch at line 238:

ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
```

Line 238 is the blank comment line here:

```
+/**
+ * Abstract helper class for {@link Zend_Pdf_FileParser} that provides the
+ * data source for parsing.
+ *
+ * Concrete subclasses allow for parsing of in-memory, filesystem, and other
+ * sources through a common API. These subclasses also take care of error
+ * handling and other mundane tasks.
```

We also tried the VI step mentioned here - :set ff unix
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/864518

The error then changed to:

```
$ sh PATCH_SUPEE-2629_EE_1.12.0.0_v1.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 1936.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 43.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php
```

Comment: Look here, maybe it will help a little bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572320/magento-1-7-2-security-patch-error-via-ssh

Comment: @sergio, thanks there were some useful ideas there although we haven't found a solution yet. Post updated with the results

Comment: Before trying to apply the patch!!! Use Chrome or Firefox to do "Save As..." on plaintext file that downloads. Make sure the patch gets uploaded with proper line endings, it's a *nix shell script and doesn't need any CRLF silliness to break it and cause syntax errors when you try to run it from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that this error is given when the **patch file** (not the file being patched) has line endings which do not match the system on which it is being run.

eg: You will see this error when:

- You are running on Linux
- Your patch file has Windows line endings

I changed the patch file to have Unix line endings using Sublime:

`View > Line Endings > Unix`

See also [Error patching Magento 1.7.1 Hunk #1 Failed at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703404/error-patching-magento-1-7-1-hunk-1-failed-at/29874041#29874041)