# Error in installing patch 7405 of magento

Tags: magento, ssh, patch, yum

I have downloaded file from this link :
https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches/blob/master/CE1.9-EE1.14/PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.0.1_v1-2016-01-20-04-45-14.sh
and has kept in root folder. when I run the command :

```
bash PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.0.1_v1-2016-01-20-04-45-14.sh
```

then it gives me error:

```
PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.0.1_v1-2016-01-20-04-45-14.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found
PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.0.1_v1-2016-01-20-04-45-14.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.0.1_v1-2016-01-20-04-45-14.sh: line 9: `_check_installed'tools() {
```

I am following this link: [Magento 1.7.2 SECURITY PATCH ERROR Via SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572320/magento-1-7-2-security-patch-error-via-ssh). I am trying running

```
yum install patch
```

but this is not getting installed as I move further it is giving me error.
Also I have not installed any previous patches, is this patch dependent on any previous patch?

I want to let you know that I had made changes in core files but now I have reverted them and after installing 4291,6237,7616 patch now I am trying to run command:

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.0.1_v1-2016-01-20-04-45-14.sh
```

Now I am getting error:

```
    checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
Hunk #2 FAILED at 43.
Hunk #3 succeeded at 64 with fuzz 2 (offset -4 lines).
1 out of 3 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Redirectpolicy.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/History.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Catalog/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image/Favicon.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Admin.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Adminhtml/Authorizenet/Directpost/PaymentController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Helper/Minsaleqty.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 166.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 177 (offset -10 lines).
1 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 65 (offset -3 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
Hunk #2 FAILED at 264.
1 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/controllers/CustomerController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
Hunk #2 FAILED at 118.
Hunk #3 succeeded at 121 (offset -12 lines).
1 out of 3 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Observer.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowadvancedController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Block/Catalog/Salesrule.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Order.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper/Guest.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
can't find file to patch at input line 2014
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
|index a3cdbc8..8b697b9 100644
|--- app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
|+++ app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/authorizenet/directpost/iframe.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/create/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/create/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/composite/fieldset/options/type/file.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/creditmemo/name.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/invoice/name.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/name.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/renderer/default.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/totals/discount.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 77 (offset -1 lines).
checking file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
checking file lib/Varien/Io/File.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 227.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
```

Comment: I recommend you download the patch from the official site https://www.magentocommerce.com/download under release archive, making sure to select the correct version your shop is running.

I found this post http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems to be a good reference to deal with upcoming errors. But you really should apply all previous patches. Also, you do not need yum to apply the patch. Simply running the bash command is enough.

Comment: I have edited my question above after installing previous patches it is not giving earlier error but a new error is coming. Please let me know what I am missing now?

Comment: thanks it worked after installing all patches : 4291,6237,7616,5344,5994,6285,6482,6788,7405

Comment: $'\r': probably indicates that this file was downloaded or uploaded in PC format with `crlf` line endings instead of `lf` line endings. It causes the Linux command interpreter to cough a hairball when that happens and you try to execute the shell script.

Comment: I was able to successfully install all patches, but now after this when I login through user in admin , it loads fine but when any ajax function is called, it is throwing 403 error. My app folder has 777 permissions, what else do I need to do. Please help my site is not working.

Comment: Belongs to https://magento.stackexchange.com